# Compression ratio

Tags: compression

I have a 20Gb tar.gz file containing mainly text and image files compressed. I want to know (without uncompressing the file) how much space it would take on my disk. How can I make an estimation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
gzip --list filename.gz
```

will tell you the size of the original uncompressed file, among other things, although not when the original size 4GB or more, like @MarkAdler points out.

Comment: Alas, that won't work in this case.  gzip will tell you the uncompressed size _modulo 2^32_.  So a 20 GB .gz will report something less than 4 GB as the uncompressed size, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you need to decompress the .gz file.  But you don't need to store it or take up all that space on your disk.

Using `gzip --list`, as suggested in another answer, won't work.  The gzip file format stores the uncompressed length in four bytes at the end, so that is only useful for those files that you know some other way for certain has a compressed length of less than 4 GB.  In this case, you know for sure that that's *not* the case, since the *compressed* size is 20 GB.  So the length reported by `gzip` is useless.

To get the uncompressed length, pipe the output of `gzip` decompression to something that will count the bytes, like `wc`.  E.g.:

```
gzip -dc < foo.tar.gz | wc -c
```

Comment: As per https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt: ISIZE (Input SIZE). This contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input data modulo 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bunch of zipped files and I needed to know the uncompressed size, so I came up with the following command:

```
find foo/*.gz -exec gzip -l '{}' \; |awk '{ sub(/uncompressed/, " "); print } {sum += $2} END {print sum}'
```